# Bat not liking "," for x,y,c

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a bat game, and for the location of the player im using x.y.c (C being the compass the player is facing) Note the use of "." and not ","

Why is it that batch doesn't like the use of ","?

What I mean  by this is if you say goto 0,0 it will crash because it cant find :0,0
However if you use goto 0.0 it can find :0.0

Comment: give the code...what do you mean `doesn't like`?

Comment: What i mean is if you use 0,0 it will crash because it cant find :0,0

Comment: goto `:0,0` does not makes sense. Why don't you show us the real "code"? And you should explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish. At least I have not idea what you are talking about.

Comment: The question appears clear; he's talking about batch file labels and gotos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As GolezTrol said, `,` isn't an allowed character for a label.
But it's even more complex, you can view it from two points.
First from the label-view:

The characters of a label will never be expanded, the name of the label stops at one of the characters `:+&|<>`, and you can't esacpe them neither with quotes nor with carets, as quotes and carets are valid label characters too.
A valid labels can prepended by ANY character (but only one) followed by many out of `SPACE,;=TAB`

The other view is from the call or goto command:

There are these characters that stops the label `<space>`, `<TAB>` and `:,;=+` even when the label is in quotes like

```
call :"myLabel+ignored"
exit /b

:"myLabel
echo It's called by %0
```

But the output will be `:"myLabel+ignored` even if the name of the searched label will be only  `"myLabel`.

`(<>` can also stop the label but not in quotes, they seem to work quite different.

With these two rules it's possible to understand how this works.

```
@echo off
call :%%%%X+Y%%
echo ---

<;;==;,,:%X<nul=echo hello 
echo Called by %0
exit /b
```

Comment: I noticed the <> when making my help file, as if you have echo Look <object> it would claim it couldnt find the file, even with echo.
(I just ended up using Look [Object])

Comment: But that is a completely different problem, you can solve it with `echo Look^<object^>`

Comment: I dont really mind not being able to use <>, I think it looks better with [] Anyway. Thanks none the less

Answer (score 3):

Labels cannot contain a `,`. This is not just in batch. 'Real' programming languages generally also don't accept the use of a comma in identifiers, although they are generally even stricter and won't allow using the period either.

I think the period is never an operator in batch, while the comma is, so to prevent abiguous expressions, they don't allow the use of a comma in an identifier.

PS: What kind of bat game are you creating? I created a text adventure once with reasonable succes, but I came to the conclusion that action games have trouble getting the timing right.

Comment: Im making a text adventure. You can try it out here, but remember its not done. Also any comments and suggestions would be helpful

http://db.tt/WYR7Ok0z

(Its also not updated, however I will post updated links if you wish)

Comment: It looks like an executable. Do you have a bat compiler?

Comment: Yes, I compiled the .bat into an exe with use of Bat_To_Exe_Converter which can be found here http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e.com